# carbon-relay eating CPU - EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)?

Tags: python, networking, ubuntu-12.04, twisted, graphite

- Python 2.7.3
- [twisted, version 13.1.0]
- xen-domU

`atop` shows that `carbon-relay` is eating 80, 90% USRCPU. From the `strace`:

```
accept(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60649), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.237.222.81")}, [16]) = 257
accept(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51564), sin_addr=inet_addr("166.78.1.48")}, [16]) = 257
accept(7, 0x7ffff4679550, [16])         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
accept(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33654), sin_addr=inet_addr("198.61.194.248")}, [16]) = 257
accept(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(50037), sin_addr=inet_addr("166.78.181.204")}, [16]) = 257
accept(7, 0x7ffff4679550, [16])         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

The strange thing is: even restart the service, it seems stuck at fd 7 everytime running `strace`. Does it mean this fd is not being cleanup properly?

I have increased the number of open files:

**/proc/2891/limits**

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             15834                15834                processes 
Max open files            16384                16384                files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       15834                15834                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

then it decreases down to ~ 50%.

My problem looks like similar to this [thread](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2008-September/018361.html) but since we have a few sockets in TIME_WAIT state, I don't think that enable the `tw_recycle` can help. About the `tcp_syncookies`, I don't see any related message in the syslog.

This is what I get when trying to start `carbon-relay` in debug mode:

```
26/11/2013 02:22:14 :: [listener] MetricPickleReceiver connection with 50.56.249.127:48772 lost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
26/11/2013 02:22:14 :: [listener] MetricPickleReceiver connection with 198.101.241.101:50672 lost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
26/11/2013 02:22:14 :: [listener] MetricPickleReceiver connection with 166.78.2.167:43346 lost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
```

This is from `twisted`:

```python
class ConnectionLost(ConnectionClosed):
    """Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion"""

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.__doc__.strip().splitlines()[0]
        if self.args:
            s = '%s: %s' % (s, ' '.join(self.args))
        s = '%s.' % s
        return s
```

I also have tried to [debug with `gdb`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) but `pystack` returns nothing.